What to fix in this build.gradle?
My Flutter's build.gradle is giving two errors: The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Documentos\projetos_flutter\curso_8-alura_flutter_client_control-main\curso_8-alura_flutter_client_control-main\android\build.gradle' (C:\Users\admin\.gradle\caches\7.6.1\scripts\5td5f46m3u3nebpnueml4y0ei).
BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 66
Unsupported class file major version 66

Error 2:  Could not open cp_init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\b8d79275f486465e075ef8cec9f7ee46\Oracle.oracle-java\userdir\var\cache\gradle\nb-tooling.gradle' (C:\Users\admin\.gradle\caches\7.6.1\scripts\3243bx45a6e2fszlw614sq37m). BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 66

And also in my terminal this appears when I run flutter pub get: 7 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints
But I can't update it
I tried several things, but it keeps giving me errors and I can't update the 7 packages

IDK Flutter, but "Dependency constraints" implies that a dependency can't be upgraded past the current version. What have you tried so far? If _BuildScript_ is accessible, please edit to include that in your post as it may help the Flutter-capable people understand what the issue is. May also be worth including the build.gradle that is mentioned, but it looks like it could be a generated file so may be inaccessible.
